# Not able to update input field value

Tags: java, jsf-2, javabeans, oracle-adf

HI all i have a **input field** on my jsf page whose value is set to a setter getter **dSecurityGroup**

```
public void setDSecurityGroup(String dSecurityGroup) {
    this.dSecurityGroup = dSecurityGroup;
}

public String getDSecurityGroup() throws IdcClientException, IOException {

    Map<String,String> mapValue=getDocumentPropertiesSystem();
    dSecurityGroup=mapValue.get("dSecurityGroup");
    return dSecurityGroup;
}
```

At first time i get the value from the getter and show it to the user, there is a **update** button on my form on click of which i am retrieving this input field value to update, but when i update the input field value and click on update button, it takes the previous value and also change the input field value to the **old one**.
How can i get the changed value..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks wrong to me. You always return

```
dSecurityGroup=mapValue.get("dSecurityGroup");
```

so as long as Thre map value doesn't change you see thus value.